# Миграции laravel not null

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделать, что бы столбец был `key - char(25) not null`?

Comment: ну как, работает?

Answer (score 1):

Документация [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#columns). Поля по умолчанию `not null`

```
$table->char('key', 25);
```